Transform value in same format as output from read(AES.block_size)
I am working on some encrypt task using python. I am using Crypto.Cipher and Crypto from python. The code I used is next:
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
iv

The output of iv is next:
'\x81zD\x80\x1a\x83\xda\x02w\xd2\xf9\x98&-^\x0e'

Because this is an encrypting task I need to define my own iv, so I have:
#Define own iv
val="643f5a4957263b6b4e72544e42593275"

My question is: how can I transform val to a similar format like the first iv I printed.
Many thanks.

No, you don't want to define your own fixed IV. Use a new random one for every encryption, and include it with the encrypted data, so it can be used by the decryption code. The different format of the IV in your code is because the first one is binary, and prints like that. Your IV (that you should not use) is a binary array value expressed as a hexadecimal string. You can convert such a string to the corresponding binary, which you would need to do in order to use it, but as mentioned you don't want to use it, since it's a very serious security problem if you do.

@Xecrets could you please help me converting such a string to the corresponding binary, this is just an example and I need the iv in 16 len format. Many thanks!

If you like that API you should still upgrade to pycryptodome which is actually supported. You may, in fact, be using it.

You want
iv = bytes.fromhex("643f5a4957263b6b4e72544e42593275")

To go the other way,
hex_bytes = iv.hex()


Yes, but... They doesn't want that, because you don't want a fixed IV.  This introduces a critical security flaw in the scheme. They want to generate a new random IV for each encryption, and include it with the cipherdata sent to the decryption code. Just saying...

@Xecrets: You don't know that this has anything to do with a fixed IV, the way I read the question. They want to know how to convert from a hex string representation of bytes to a bytes object.

Seemed like a fair assumption, the original question was:
"Because this is an encrypting task I need to define my own iv, so I have:
#Define own iv
val="643f5a4957263b6b4e72544e42593275"
"
and
"...I need the iv in 16 len format"
In this context it seems fairly likely that the intention is to store a fixed IV as a string in the source code.
If not - the warning's been issued, and your answer to the literal question "how to convert a hex string to bytes" seems appropriate.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I am getting this AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'fromhex', do I need to load something package? Many thanks!

@Duck: I don't have your code so I can't be sure. Perhaps you have defined a variable named bytes. If so, it is shadowing the bytes built-in class which is a bad idea. Name the variable something else.
